# Finding the largest, second largest, second smallest, and smallest int from an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, max, minimum

I'm using a method to print the largest, second largest, smallest, and second smallest integers. This is what I have so far for the base:

```
     case 1:
        System.out.print("\nEnter the Limit: ");
        limit = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println(pairs(limit));
        break;
```

This is the method being called so far:

```
// Case 1 Method : Largest and Smallest Pairs
   public static String pairs(int limit) {
      System.out.println("*** Largest and Smallest Pairs");
      return "";
   }
```

The actual output is to formatted like
(largest,secondlargest),(smallest,secondsmallest)
I've never used an array before, and I'm not sure how to use loops with it to find the values. How do I begin this?

Here is the complete code for my program. You can disregard the second and third case, however, I still need help with the third. I need to display all prime numbers in order. Here is the requirement: Twin Prime Numbers: This should let the user specify a limit n (I used limit instead) (if n is 1000, then consider 1
to 1000), and lists the pairs of twin primes up to n. The sample run is (3,5),(5,7),(11,13),(17,19)

The complete code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PatternChecker{

   // The scanner is accessible for every method included
   static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      // Variables
      int limit;

      System.out.println("List of Pattern Checker problems:\n1) Largest and Smallest Pairs\n2) Patterns of Triangles\n3) Twin Prime Pairs\n4) Quit");
      System.out.print("Choice: ");
      int choice = input.nextInt();

      // The switch statement for the variable "choice" and each case
      switch (choice) {
         default:
            System.out.println("\n*** INVALID OPTION");
            break;
         case 1:
            System.out.print("\nEnter the Limit: ");
            limit = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println(pairs(limit));
            break;
         case 2:
            System.out.println("\nEnter the Limit: ");
            limit = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println(triangleOne(limit));
            System.out.println(triangleTwo(limit));
            System.out.println(triangleThree(limit));
            System.out.println(triangleFour(limit));
            break;
         case 3:
            System.out.println("\nEnter the Limit: ");
            limit = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println(primePairs(limit));
            break;
         case 4:
            System.out.println("\n*** End");
            break;
      }
   }

   // Case 1 Method : Largest and Smallest Pairs
   public static String pairs(int limit) {
      System.out.println("*** Largest and Smallest Pairs");
      return "";
   }
// Case 2 Method: Patterns of Triangles (Triangle One)
   public static String triangleOne(int limit) {
      System.out.println("*** Patterns of Triangles");
      for (int x = 1; x <= limit; x++) {
         for (int y = 1; y <= x; y++) {
            System.out.print(y + " ");
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
      return "";
   }
   // Case 2 Method: Patterns of Triangles (Triangle Two)
   public static String triangleTwo(int limit) {
      for (int x = limit; x > 0; x--) {
         for (int y = 1; y <= x; y++) {
            System.out.print(y + " ");
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
      return "";
   }
   // Case 2 Method: Patterns of Triangles (Triangle Three)
   public static String triangleThree(int limit) {
      for (int row = 1; row <= limit; row++) {
         for (int space = (limit - row); space > 0; space--) {
            System.out.print("  ");
         }
         for (int num = row; num > 0; num--) {
            System.out.print(num + " ");
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
      return "";
   }
   // Case 2 Method: Patterns of Triangles (Triangle Four)
   public static String triangleFour(int limit) {
      for (int row = limit; row >= 0; row--) {
         for (int space = (limit - row); space > 0; space--) {
            System.out.print("  ");
         }
         for (int num = 1; num <= row; num++) {
            System.out.print(num + " ");
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
      return "";
   }
// Case 3 Method: Twin Prime Pairs
   public static String primePairs(int limit) {
      System.out.println("*** Twin Prime Numbers up to " + limit);

      return "";
   }
}
```

Comment: I cannot see any array here... so what is your question? What is `limit` and why is there a single `case` without a switch? Please provide a minimal testable code fraction that explains your problem!

Comment: It should explain more @JoshuaK

Comment: do u need it from an array or a list would also work ?

Comment: I have no idea how to do it, im just assuming an array @user641887

Comment: ok i have written a quick answer with lists.. hope this helps.

Comment: Please upvote the answer and mark as answered it it helped you in your problem

Answer (score 0):

Ok based on the comment i have written a quick answer with arraylists. hope this helps.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MaxMin {

    private List<Integer> alist = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        MaxMin maxmin = new MaxMin();
        maxmin.init();

    }

    public void init() {

        System.out.println("Welcome!!!");
        readFromUser();
        printUserList();
        doSort();
        display();  
    }

    public void readFromUser() {

        Scanner scanner = null;

        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter the total number of elements :");
            Integer totalElements = scanner.nextInt();

            for (int i=0;i<totalElements;i++) {
                System.out.print("Enter the " + i +" number");
                alist.add(scanner.nextInt());
            }

        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            scanner.close();
        }

    }

    public void printUserList() {

        System.out.println("user entered list is :");
        System.out.println(alist);
    }

    public void doSort() {

        Collections.sort(alist);
    }

    public void display() {

        System.out.println("(" +alist.get(alist.size()-1)+ "," +alist.get(alist.size()-2)+ ")" + "(" +alist.get(0)+"," +alist.get(1) +")"); 
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this isn't a homework problem, but the idea is to use a loop with the array, and keep track of the largest and smallest numbers.

Start with assigning the smallest number variable to Integer.MAX_VALUE, so the first number you check will be assigned to the smallest number, because all integer values except 2^31 - 1 are smaller than Integer.MAX_VALUE, and you do that for biggest too, but with Integer.MIN_VALUE.

And then whenever you assign the biggest number again, you assign the secondBiggest variable to the "biggest" variable.

With that in mind, you just need to loop through the values of the array and check if they're larger than the biggest (in which you re-assign it) or smaller than the smallest(same thing as biggest).

```
int[] array = new int[]{5, 3, 4, 1, 2};

for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

^
Example of looping through an array

Comment: The other answer is better, but if you're going to use it, it needs to account for if the array has less than two elements.

Answer (score 0):

I created an example for you.

First of all it generates a list of prime numbers till the limit (in this case hardcoded 100). Next it asks for all prime pairs and prints them. The pairs are stored in an ArrayList so it is very easy to get the first and the last pair.

It's not realy hard to understand so I don't know what to explain. Take a look at the code and if you have any questions feel free to ask.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PatternChecker {
  public ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PatternChecker pc = new PatternChecker();
    pc.detectPrimes(100);
    ArrayList<int[]> numbers = pc.getPairs();
    System.out.println("Print all pairs: ");
    numbers.stream().forEach((intA)->System.out.println(intA[0]+" / "+intA[1]));
    System.out.println("Print just the greatest and the smallest pair: ");
    System.out.println("("+numbers.get(0)[0]+","+numbers.get(0)[1]+")");
    System.out.println("("+numbers.get(numbers.size()-1)[0]+","+numbers.get(numbers.size()-1)[1]+")");
  }

  public void detectPrimes(int limit) {
    for(int i=2;i<limit;i++)
      if(isPrime(i))
        primes.add(i);
  }
  protected boolean isPrime(int no) {
    for(int i=0;i<primes.size();i++)
      if(no % primes.get(i) == 0) return false;
    return true;
  }
  public ArrayList<int[]> getPairs() {
    ArrayList<int[]> result = new ArrayList<>();
    int last = primes.get(0);
    for(int i=1;i<primes.size();i++) {
      if(primes.get(i)==last+2) {
        int[] resH = new int[2];
        resH[0] = last;
        resH[1] = primes.get(i);
        result.add(resH);
      }
      last = primes.get(i);
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```